# Newest messages first (PHP)

Tags: php, comments, fwrite

I am following this tutorial to create a comment system: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bgdhcqlMXg. But, I want the newest message to appear first, not the oldest.

So I remplaced "a" by "w+" (I've also tried "c" and "r+", but I got the same problem).

```
<?php 
if($_POST) {
$message = $_POST['message'];
$handle = fopen("includes/messages.php", "w+");
file_put_contents($message, $handle);
fwrite($handle,"<h2>Name</h2><p>'.$message.'</p>");
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

And, instead of posting different "box" for one message, the code is only replacing the previous message. For exemple:

The user write "Awesome" in the textarea, it will publish "Awesome".
But If a second user write "I love coding", "Awesome" will transform into "I love coding". (Instead of being 2 different comments).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
// if POST request not empty
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    // Set filename
    $filename = 'includes/messages.php';

    $input_msg = $_POST['message'];

    // Get all messages
    $old_msg = file_get_contents($filename);

    // Add new message to the beginning
    $new_msg = "<h2>Name</h2><p>'.$message.'</p>".$old_msg;

    // Save it
    file_put_contents($filename, $new_msg, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Comment: @SuperYéti: Can you show the code that displays the messages?

Comment: Yes, sure: http://i.imgur.com/k0sv851.png I've tried to replace it by your code but it didn't worked.

Comment: @SuperYéti: This is the same code that is in the question. This code does not display anything. I'm asking you to share the code that displays the messages from the file.

Comment: I have a <form action="" method="POST"> and this PHP code + a message.php file.

Comment: What does that message.php file contain? Could you show that code?

Comment: message.php contain nothing. message.php is just here to receive the comments.

Comment: Do you see the "Name" part and the messages below the "Publier De Message" button? I'm asking you to show the code that displays those messages. How exactly is that getting displayed there?

Comment: Do you mind sharing all the complete files on pastebin? Since your replies do not really help. He is asking for the whole file, not a HTML line.

Comment: I don't have a ton of code, If you watch the YouTube video I showed you. There is only the PHP code, the HTML <form> and message.php (message.php = comments.html in the video).

Comment: I don't have time to watch the YouTube video, and you can have something misspelled.

Comment: @SuperYéti: Stack Overflow is designed to be a repository of helpful questions and answers. The question you just wrote is a part of the repository and the folks that are going to view the question months later won't benefit from it if the relevant part of the code is in a YouTube video somewhere.

Comment: But, all the code that is in the video I gave it to you. The video is just here to be an additional help for users to understand me.

Comment: What code do you want? You asked for the code inside message.php but there is nothing except the HTML code of the comments that users posted.

Comment: @TomášAresakMalčánek, yes I've used the code of Amal Murali.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
file_put_contents($file, $message, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

be aware you should use lock_ex beacuse if 2 process run in sametime file will be wrong ,and lock help u to one of  writer in same time can write .

Answer (score 0):

First, **Please indent your code!** I cannot stress that enough about good programming techniques.

Second, don't check `$_POST`, check `$_POST['message']`. This is to make sure the actual message is sent through and not just any `$_POST` values.

Finally, the reason it is not working is because of how you are storing it. I would not store messages in a file. Store it in the database. I am not sure if you are trying to `include()` the `messages.php` file, or if you are drectly storing info in i. For an application like this, don't store info in files like that. Use a database like MySQL. In MySQL you could do calls like this.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'messages');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE /* Whatever you want to specify here */

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        echo $row['message'];            

    }
?>
```

This would assume you have a database called **messages**, and a column called **message**.

Check out [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL442FA2C127377F07) over PHP. It is really good. A bit outdated, but a good refresher.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't want to use SQL. I am trying to avoid using it.

Comment: @SuperYéti It is understandable, but if in the future you want to have a major site, you will have to use a database to store info, because multiple pages will be too much on a server.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But my website is only open for 50 people, so I think it is okay.